# Why is my pointer ("char *item") variable being treated as a regular variable ("char item")?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, stack

I have a stack implementation that stores variable: char *items on the stack. But for some reason when I use stack->items[position], it treats it as a regular char (not a pointer) and I am unable to store the full char (it is a URL) on the stack.

I want to give the push function a char * (that is a URL) and I want to take that and put in on my stack, that is either:

```
p->items[p->pos] = item;
```

or

```
strcpy(p->items[p->pos], item);
```

Here is the part of the code that gives the error:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "shm_stack.h"

typedef struct int_stack{
      int size;               /* the max capacity of the stack */
      int pos;                /* position of last item pushed onto the stack */
      char *items;             /* stack of stored chars */
} ISTACK;

int is_full(ISTACK *p){
      if ( p == NULL ) {
          return 0;
      }
      return ( p->pos == (p->size -1) );
}

int sizeof_shm_stack(int size){
      return (sizeof(ISTACK) + sizeof(char) * size);
}

int init_shm_stack(ISTACK *p, int stack_size){
      if ( p == NULL || stack_size == 0 ) {
          return 1;
      }

      p->size = stack_size;
      p->pos  = -1;
      p->items = (char *) (p + sizeof(ISTACK));
      return 0;
}


ISTACK *create_stack(int size){
      int mem_size = 0;
      ISTACK *pstack = NULL;

      if ( size == 0 ) {
          return NULL;
      }

      mem_size = sizeof_shm_stack(size);
      pstack = malloc(mem_size);

      if ( pstack == NULL ) {
          perror("malloc");
      } else {
          char *p = (char *)pstack;
          pstack->items = (char *) (p + sizeof(ISTACK));
          pstack->size = size;
          pstack->pos  = -1;
      }

      return pstack;
}

void destroy_stack(ISTACK *p){
      if ( p != NULL ) {
          free(p);
      }
}

int push(ISTACK *p, char *item){
      if ( p == NULL ) {
          return -1;
      }

      if ( !is_full(p) ) {
          ++(p->pos);
          //p->items[p->pos] = item;
          strcpy(p->items[p->pos], item);
          //printf("push method: %d\n", p->items[p->pos]);
          return 0;
      } else {
          return -1;
      }
}
```

The issue is in my push method where I can neither use strcpy() or just assign the char to p->items[p-pos] without it saying something like "assigning char from incompatible type char *", but dereferencing "item" will only get me the first character, and I want the entire "string".

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: `p->items[p->pos]` is a single character. You need a 2D array. e.g. `char **items;` and then do dynamic allocation. You haven't shown how you allocate the `items` field so it is difficult to explain how that would fit into your code.

Comment: Note also that `strcpy` is in no way equivalent to pointer assignment.  You could build a stack using either approach, but there are different considerations for these, and these impact multiple facets of how you design, build and use the result.

Comment: @kaylum `char **items;` is not a 2D array, though it can be used to implement a data structure that acts like a 2D array.

Comment: @kaylum I've included how I initialized the fields. I ended up getting a sort of starter code/template for the stack (but instead of using char* they used int*) so I thought I could just change the int* to char* though now I am not quite sure if that is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

`p->items` is a `char*`, so `p->items[...]` is a `char`. `strcpy` expects a `char*`, so there's a mismatch between what you provide and what's needed.

Not only that, it expects the pointer to point to the first of enough characters to contain the string being copied in. You did not even attempt to get the length of the string pointed by `item`, much less allocate enough memory for it.

---

I presume you want a stack of strings. If so, we need a array of pointers (`char *items[]`) or a pointer to a block of memory for pointers (`char **items`). The latter is simpler here. As such,

```c
char *items;
```

should be

```c
char **items;
```

It would be allocated using

```c
malloc(sizeof(char*) * size)
```

---

There are two approaches to adding a string to the stack.

1. The stack could take ownership of the string provided.

   ```c
   p->items[p->pos] = item;
   ```
2. The stack could make a copy of the string provided.

   ```c
   p->items[p->pos] = strdup(item);
   ```

The difference is in who is responsible for freeing the string.

Comment: thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense. Though in the template code, they had used "int *items" (and just replace all the chars* with int*), but it worked for them when they did "p->items[p->pos] = item". Why does it work for int but not char?

Comment: You can't store multiple ints in an int.